# Как убрать ожидания выполнения функции в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, многопоточность, telebot, multiprocessing

Я создаю telegram baton telebot с генерацией изображений в stable diffusion, я использую *automatic 1111* и через *requests* подключаюсь к http://127.0.0.1:7860 и работайте с запросами к нему. Проблема в том, что когда пользователь делает запрос и начинается генерация изображения, bat перестает отвечать на новые сообщения в боте. ****Как заставить bat продолжать отвечать на запросы, и когда запрашивается новое поколение, путем постановки его в очередь.***

Ниже приведен код функции генерации изображений:

```
def generate(propmt, user_id):
    payload = {
        "prompt": propmt,
        "steps": 20,
        "negative_prompt": "negative promt",
        "sampler_index": "DPM++ 2M Karras",
        "width": 512,
        "height": 756,
        "hr_scale": 2,
        "enable_hr": True,
        "hr_upscaler": "R-ESRGAN 4x+ Anime6B",
        "hr_second_pass_steps": 40,
        "denoising_strength": 0.9,
        "cfg_scale": 10,
    }
    my_file = open("outs" + f"\\{user_id}tx" + '.txt', "w+")
    my_file.write(propmt)
    my_file.close()
    response = requests.post(url=f'{url}/sdapi/v1/txt2img', json=payload)

    r = response.json()

    for i in r['images']:
        image = Image.open(io.BytesIO(base64.b64decode(i.split(",", 1)[0])))

        png_payload = {
            "image": "data:image/png;base64," + i
        }
        response2 = requests.post(url=f'{url}/sdapi/v1/png-info', json=png_payload)

        pnginfo = PngImagePlugin.PngInfo()
        pnginfo.add_text("parameters", response2.json().get("info"))
        image.save("outs" + f"\\{user_id}" + '.png', pnginfo=pnginfo)
```

Вот как эта функция запускается в обработчике обратного вызова:

```
bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id,
                                     "✏️ Генерация началась, обычно это занимает две - три минуты, но может больше. \n\nЗайдите через две минуты и нажмите Меню - /get, чтобы получить результат")
                    p2 = Process(target=generate(promt_user, user_id_glob))
                    p2.start()
```

Я новичок в процессах, поэтому такой запуск может оказаться бесполезным.

Как заставить бота продолжать отвечать на новые сообщения?

Я пытался использовать многопроцессорную обработку, но, скорее всего, я сделал это неправильно. Бот продолжает ждать, пока генерация изображения не закончится и наступит момент, когда система будет свободна от задач.